# How to make .properties file compile time for @FindBy constants

Tags: java, selenium, annotations, webdriver

I am using a `.properties` file for object repository in Selenium webdriver in `@FindBy()`.

I am getting an error as `@FindBy` needs a constant value to initialize.

Is there a way to make `.properties` file compile work?

Code snippet:

```
public class LoginPageID {

    @FindBy(id=ObjectConstants.LOGINID) 
    public WebElement LoginID; 
}

public class ObjectConstants { 
    public static final String LOGINID; 

    static { 
    Properties p = new Properties();

    try { 
        p.load(new FileInputStream("constants.properties"));
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        LOGINID = p.getProperty("LOGINID"); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Such trick is not possible in Java. Your constant's value will be available only in runtime on first `ObjectConstants` access. That's why IDE reports an error to you.

I got your idea, and it seems realistic to me. But...
The main challenge in this particular case is related to 3rd party (WebDriver), which you cannot easily redefine.

So technically you have to create your own annotation, which will ideally consume a parameterized enum value. For example:

```
public enum Locator {
    LOGIN_INPUT(getProperty("login")),
    PASSWORD_INPUT(getProperty("password"));

    private final String val;

    Locator(final String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Find {

    Locator value();
}
```

Then you'll need a custom factory for enum values extraction, proxying fields or whatever approach you gonna use.